# Python "if does not exist, then..." logic?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

With the following dataframe, I'm trying to create a new `guest_1` column that takes the first two words in each item of the `guest` column. At the bottom, you can see my desired output.

Is there some sort of "if doesn't exist, then..." logic I can apply here?

I've tried the following, but the obvious difficulty is accounting for a person with a single word for a name.

`df.guest_1 = data.guest.str.split().str.get(0) + ' ' + data.guest.str.split().str.get(1)`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': ['2018-11-21','2018-02-26'],
     'guest': ['Anthony Scaramucci & Michael Avenatti', 'Robyn'],
    })

df.guest_1 = ['Anthony Scaramucci', 'Robyn']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split, slice, and join. This will gracefully handle out-of-bounds slices:

```
df.guest.str.split().str[:2].str.join(' ')
```

---

```
df['guest_1'] = df.guest.str.split().str[:2].str.join(' ')
df

         date                                  guest             guest_1
0  2018-11-21  Anthony Scaramucci & Michael Avenatti  Anthony Scaramucci
1  2018-02-26                                  Robyn               Robyn
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess `get` was the wrong approach to take here.

Comment: @bbk611 You might have figured this out on your own if you'd noticed `.str.get(n)` is the same as `.str[n]`, then you''d be able to generalise to slices from there: `.str[i:j]`